# Does Common Lisp (SBCL) have high level parallelism functions?

Tags: parallel-processing, common-lisp, sbcl

In Haskell, I'm able to enable parallel evaluation of lists using:

```
map expensiveFunction list `using` parList rdeepseq
```

Adding only the `` `using` parList rdeepseq `` enables the pure parallel computation and runs 4 times faster on my quad-core processor.

Is there a similar capability using SBCL?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Common Lisp doesn't have a standard facility to do this, but there is a library designed to do exactly this that is well supported on most CL implementations: [Lparallel](http://lparallel.org/)

With lparallel you can do the following:

```
(let ((number-sets '((1 2 3) (4 5 6) (10 11 12 13 14) (100 200 300))))
  (lparallel:pmap 'list (lambda (v) (apply #'+ v)) number-sets))
```

This will perform the individual summations in parallel, but otherwise return the same result as if one had used plain `map`.

Comment: Thanks! Did not know about this library.